# Access Denied when saving a file in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I just upgraded to 7 this evening (yes, it's still evening for me, not yet slept).

I am installing some new programs and needed to make a modification to a file within the newly created directory. When I try and save this file, I get Access Denied.

I am currently set up as an administrator. I found another post that offered to use "net user administrator /active:yes" from a command line but that didn't work either. I also got access denied.

Can anyone tell me what the procedure is for saving a simple text file as an admin?

Can anyone offer a suggestion. I'm still stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have the permissions required to access this directory.

This article explains how to grant such permissions:
[How To Change File/Folder Permissions In Windows 7](http://www.dkszone.net/how-to-change-filefolder-permissions-in)

If this is a directory that you'll like to be the owner, see:
[Take and Grant Full Control Permissions and Ownership in Windows 7](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/21/take-and-grant-full-control-permissions-and-ownership-in-windows-7-or-vista-right-click-menu/)

However, exercise some caution if the directory in question belongs to the system.

Comment: Thanks for the links and great info. The directory that I am trying to save the file in was created by aother program. I need to edit this file and then save it before the program will function properly. I'd like to leave the directory set to its rightful owner and not take ownership of it. Which of your options would work best for me?

Comment: Because of user account control (UAC) even though you are an administrator you are running with lower privileges.  Rather than changing the ownership, run an elevated explorer.  Right click on an the Windows Explorer icon and choose "Run As Administrator".  The you will have full access to everything accessed from that window.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I right click on the windows explorer icon in my taskbar, I do not see that option at all. Does it matter that I am using "Ultimate"?

Comment: OK, I found the menu you were talking about and ran explorer as Administrator but still get the access denied error when I try and save the file. :\

Comment: How are you saving the file?

Comment: Harry, I followed your second link and got this to work. By downloading the reg file and then granting full control, I'm once again able to do the simple things like edit a text file. Man, microshaft sucks. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the application '[Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html)' to view any restrictions or program conflicts with that file.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It unfortunately didn't work. I'm about to go back to XP. This is crazy..